# Angular material 11 : mat-form-field with appearance outline to have customized border radius throughout the project

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I am starting with a new project on Angular 11 using Material components.

How can we customize styling components like input, button, card, etc.
Styling more w.r.t style of components ( sharp / rounded corners / rounded border, etc ) and not just color or typography.

Comment: You will have to fiddle with the css in the developer tools, then save the css-changes with appropriate selectors in the global css-file

Answer (score -1):

In your `angular.json` add

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Then using the correct selector for the angular material components add style like you would any other element:

Example:

```
button.mat-raised-button {
 border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```